# Вставка подстроки в строку после заданного символа

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Функция:

```
//task5 - Вставка подстроки в строку после заданного символа.
void insert_str(char* str, const char* substr, char c) {
    const char* temp = str_chr(str, c);
    char *s2 = str;
    if (!temp) throw - 1;
    
    int lena = strlen(str), lenb = strlen(temp), lenc = strlen(substr);
    
    s2[lena - lenb] = '\0';
    int lend = strlen(s2);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < lenc; i++) {
        s2[i+lend] = *substr;
        substr++;
    }
 
    int lene = strlen(s2);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < lenb; i++) {
        s2[i+lene] = *temp;
        temp++;
    }
 
    str = copy(str, s2);
 
}
```

Основная программа:

```
int main() {

    char s1[Max_Length] = "Hello World", s2[Max_Length] = "With Love", c = 'W';

    insert_str(s1, s2, c);
    cout << s1 << endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

По какой-то причине получается не "Hello With Love World", а "Hello With LoveWith" :(

Answer (score 1):

У вас ваш код даже не компилируется...

Вот, в предположении, что места в строках для вставки у вас хватает:

```
void insert_str(char* str, const char* substr, char c)
{
    char* t = strchr(str, c);
    if (!t) throw runtime_error("Char is absent");
    ++t;

    memmove(t+strlen(substr),t,strlen(t)+1);
    memmove(t,substr,strlen(substr));
}
```

И вы получаете, как и просили:

```
Hello WWith Loveorld
```

Вы же просили вставить **ПОСЛЕ** заданного символа? :)